# Where are Enum stored?

Tags: c, enums

Structures have logical existence and come into life when a structure variable is defined. I want to know how are enum's stored do they come into life immediately after there declaration. Is it just a logical existence ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
enum tag{
a,
b};
struct tag1 {
int temp;
}var;
int main(){
int a=9;
printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
printf("%d\n",var.temp);
}
```

I have heard that enums are not stored in memory so my question is from where does b get its value from.

Comment: A small code sample to discuss will really help clear up what you mean. I'm afraid I don't follow you.

Comment: No. [edit] your question with it please.

Comment: The `b` in the function is the name of the enumeration constant `b` (value `1`).  The integer variable `a` in the function hides ('shadows') the enumeration constant `a`; you can't refer to the enumeration constant `a` inside `main()` after you've declared the local variable `a`.  The variable is assigned `9`, Read about variable scopes — that's crucial to understanding this code.  The structure type exists and you declared a variable `var` at file (global) scope; it is initialized with zeros.  Consequently, your code prints `9 1 0` over two lines..

Comment: "Is it just a logical existence?" It exists in the same way a `7` or an `'x'` exists.

Comment: Where is the enumerator constant b present. And When are enumerator assignements done.?

Answer (score 3):

A standard enum is usually implemented as an int32, the compiler will handle your enum as a synonym of int32 .Once a list of values is created for a enumeration those values are stored as literals against their display name(access name given at the time of declaration of enum). Hence your enum is at the end an int32 which is hardcoded into the memory similarly like a constant.

Comment: Enumeration _constants_ are _always_ implemented as `int` - this is required by the standard. Which may in turn be 32 bit (common) or 16 bit (common) or something exotic (only possible in theory).  Enumeration _variables_ may however be of other integer types than `int` - adaptive to the size required to hold all listed constants.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is substituted with its value (1 in your case) during the compilation. Therefore it will be treated in a same way as a constant and it is not possible to get its address like a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you to take a look at the definition of object [N1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) 3.15 **object**:

> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values

and **constant** 6.4.4 (p2):

> Each constant has a type, determined by its form and value, as
>   detailed later

So it is not specified if a constant requires storage in the execution environment and hence may exist only at compile-time.

Since `enumeration constant` is a `constant` it is not specified for them either.  String literal, for instance are place in the `.rodata` section and therefore can be read, but modifying it most likely yeilds `SEGV` (although it is UB).

To be more specific, let's try to look at the `.rodata` section in your example. Here is `objdump -dj .rodata bin_name`:

```
Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000000720 <_IO_stdin_used>:
 720:   01 00 02 00 25 64 20 25 64 0a 00 25 64 0a 00        ....%d %d..%d..
```

As you can see it contains the only string literal.

Comment: The string literal begins at `25`. The `01 00` might be the enumeration constants for all we know (but probably something else).

Comment: @Lundin Anyway, I tend to assyme that compilers can optimize this away so I would no rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration constants are values. They behave like other integer values, such as 3 or −87. The compiler builds them into the code as it desires: They may be encoded as immediate operands in instructions, loaded from memory the compiler uses to hold constants, or built into expressions that are partly or completely evaluated at compile time.

Values do not have any lifetime in C’s abstract model of computation. Only objects have lifetimes, and values are not objects. (Objects are reserved portions of memory that are used to represent values.)